# Series with count larger than certain number

Tags: pandas

Given this code in iPython

```
df1=df["BillingContactCountry"].value_counts()
df1
```

I get

```
United States                      4138
Germany                            1963
United Kingdom                      732
Switzerland                         528
Australia                           459
Canada                              369
Japan                               344
France                              303
Netherlands                         285
```

I want to get a series with count larger than 303, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need[`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df1[df1 > 303])
United States     4138
Germany           1963
United Kingdom     732
Switzerland        528
Australia          459
Canada             369
Japan              344
Name: BillingContactCountry, dtype: int64
```